# How to declare an array of objects within *ngfor in angular 4?

Tags: angular

when I am using `[(ngModel)]` in my code to assign the input for an array of objects, it is not working. It seems that `model[i].jobQty` is the problem.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div *ngFor="let value of dayNum ; let i = index" >Day {{value+1}}
    <input type="number" id="jobQty" [(ngModel)]="model[i].jobQty">
    {{model[i].jobQty}}
  </div>
</div
```

Your help will be very grateful.

The idea is to have the following in my front end

```
Day   Jobqty   Date
1     5        17Jan
2     10       20 Jan
3     2        21 Jan
4     9        22 Jan
```

The code is on Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jM3NDu7V3AjzOWeuCoDi?p=preview

Comment: Where do you set `model`?

Comment: in my export class app, private model =[];

Comment: At some point you need to do something like `model.push({ jobQty })`

Comment: Model is empty! How are you trying to access an index in an empty array?

Comment: @callback it is empty because i want to input in it. I have updated my question

Comment: So where is this `jobQty` going to initially come from to fill the ngModel when it first loads?

Comment: I have updated the codes. can you please have a look

Comment: why are you just pushing a number to your array, why not push objects, since that is what you want... something like this crude sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/zV8Ik1ynJOr0105tULZS?p=preview

Comment: I dont think you then need an extra array if you can use `dayNum` for the ngModel.

Comment: @Alex Excellent it works great!!!

Comment: My idea is that your for make this.model.push({jobQty:0}). But decide. You only need one unique array

Comment: @Eliseo I guess your idea will also work perfectly